# Prolog - implementing formula of area

Tags: prolog

I want to calculate the area of a polygon in Prolog.

The area of a polygon is given by the formula:

```
| {(x1*y2-y1*x2) + (x2*y3-y2*x3) + .... + (xn*y1 - yn*x1)}/2 |
```

where `(x1,y1),(x2,y2)....(xn,yn)` are the points of the polygon.

this is my attempt to implement the formula in Prolog:

```
area(Points,Area):-areaAcc(Points,0,Area).

areaAcc([(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)|List], Acc, Area):-
    areaAcc2([(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)|List], Acc, Area, (X1,Y1)).

areaAcc2([(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)|List],Acc,Area,(FirstX,FirstY)):- 
    NewAcc is (X1*Y2-Y1*X2) + Acc,
    areaAcc2([(X2,Y2)|List], NewAcc, Area, (FirstX,FirstY)).

areaAcc2([(Xm,Ym),(Xn,Yn)|[]],Acc,Area,(FirstX,FirstY)):- 
    Area is abs((Acc + (Xn*FirstY - Yn*FirstX))/2).
```

but when I run :

```
 area([(4,10),(9,7),(11,2),(2,2),(4,10)],Area).
```

I get  `Area = 51.5`  instead of the right answer:  `Area = 45.5`. 
can anyone recognize my mistake?

Comment: When you get to the last two elements, it will match BOTH of your `areaAcc2/4` clauses: `[(2,2),(4,10)]` matches `[(Xm,Ym),(Xn,Yn)|[]]` and `[(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)|List]` (for `List=[]`). It's then probably counting the last two points twice. If rectify that it should work properly. HINT: your last clause doesn't use `(Xm,Ym)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simplify the base case (the last clause), *and* pass a not closed polygon, the result is correct

```
areaAcc2([(Xn,Yn)],Acc,Area,(FirstX,FirstY)):- 
    Area is abs((Acc + (Xn*FirstY - Yn*FirstX))/2).
```

yields

```
?- area([(4,10),(9,7),(11,2),(2,2)], A).
A = 45.5
```

Otherwise, implementing with library support it's easier:

```
area_poly(Points, A) :-
    aggregate_all(sum(E), 
        (append(_, [(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)|_], Points), E is (X1*Y2-Y1*X2)), A2),
    A is abs(A2/2).
```

Note that is misses the last sum of the formula, yet it yields the correct value, because we pass an already closed polygon...

```
?- area_poly([(4,10),(9,7),(11,2),(2,2),(4,10)], A).
A = 45.5.
```

*edit* aggregate_all/3 is available in SWI-Prolog and YAP (shared source code, I think), and - from [Internet search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=library%28aggregate%29%20prolog&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) - on SICStus Prolog. I think all these derived from Quintus Prolog. About implementation, I sketched [lag](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets), but of course reusing library code is better...

Comment: Most Prolog compilers do not provide a library with a `aggregate_all` predicate. Answering Prolog generic questions with solutions that only work in one or two Prolog dialects but without mention that requirement rises the risk of people trying the solution with other dialects and concluding that those dialects are broken or, even worse, that Prolog is not a reliable programming language.

Comment: @PauloMoura: you're absolutely right. OTOH I think the lack of aggregates is effectively a 'bug' of Prolog. Maybe could be also better if it was simpler, but with a syntax similar to SQL GROUP BY.

Comment: May I suggest that you improve your answer by mentioning which Prolog systems provide a `aggregate_all/3` library predicate usable for the alternative solution? Also how to make that predicate available for the implementation of the `area_poly/2` predicate.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I sweated over this sort of problem. But working from

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html
- http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Shoelace_Theorem
- http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea2.html

This is my take on a solution (assuming that the points are properly ordered):

```
area_polygon( []            , _ ) :- ! , fail . % not a polygon.
area_polygon( [P1]          , _ ) :- ! , fail . % 1 single point is not a polygon.
area_polygon( [P1,P2]       , _ ) :- ! , fail . % 2 points is a line segment and not a polygon.
area_polygon( [P1,P2,P3|Ps] , A ) :-            % now we're getting somehere: 3 points is a triangle.
  append( [P1,P2,P3|Ps] , [P1] , X ) ,          % append the first point to the list so it ends where it started.
  area_polygon( X , 0.0 , A )                   % call the worker predicate, seeding its accumulator with 0.0
  .

area_polygon( [] , T , A ) :- A is abs( T ) / 2.0 .
area_polygon( [(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)|Ps] , T , A ) :-
  T1 is T + (X1+X2) * (Y2-Y1) ,
  area_polygon( [(X2,Y2)|Ps] , T1 , A )
  .
```

You might not need the call to `append/3` depending on how you represent the polygon.